# java charset decode issue

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, encode

I'm trying to decode a char `·` using charset *GB2312* in java

this char contained in *GB2312*, the positional code is `a1a4` [check here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/GB2312/list.htm)

**code:**

```
public static void main(String[] _args) throws Exception {
    String str="a1a4:· a5f6:ヶ a8c5:ㄅ";          
    ByteBuffer bf=readToByteBuffer(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));
    System.out.println(Charset.forName("GB2312").decode(bf).toString());
}
private static final int bufferSize = 0x20000;
static ByteBuffer readToByteBuffer(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufferSize);
    int read;
    while (true) {
        read = inStream.read(buffer);
        if (read == -1)
            break;
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    ByteBuffer byteData = ByteBuffer.wrap(outStream.toByteArray());
    return byteData;
}
```

The code above output results for:

```
a1a4:? a5f6:ヶ a8c5:ㄅ
```

I don't understand why can't decode `a1a4`?

Comment: I assume that `IO.string2InputStream(d)` writes using the GB2312 charset as well. Have you checked whether the bytes in the buffer are correct?

Comment: @RussellZahniser sorry about that,edited my question.

Comment: You probably want to do `str.getBytes("GB2312")` - you are using the default, which is probably UTF8. But I think seh is right about it being a character issue rather than an encoding one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my browser, your string `d` has its fifth character encoded as `0xB7`, which is `MIDDLE DOT`, not `KATAKANA MIDDLE DOT`. However, according to the same database you mentioned, that code point [is not available in the *GB2312* character set](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b7/charset_support.htm). Likewise, [you can see](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/GB2312/list.htm) that neither `MIDDLE DOT` nor an encoding of `0xB7` are listed as being part of *GB2312*.

I think the problem here is with the characters in your input string, not in the [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) provided by your JRE.